# How to use Retrofit to upload a file with http put

Tags: http, retrofit, put

I am trying to upload a file with http PUT method,
I tried with OkHttp successfully, but failed with Retrofit.

Here is my codes :
  static final String MEDIA_TYPE=“image/jpeg”

```
// file is  a file path

RequestBody requestBody = getRequestBody(file);

OkHttpClient client = getOkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .put(requestBody)
        .build();

okhttp3.Response response = response = client.newCall(request).execute();

private RequestBody getRequestBody(String filePath) {
    MediaType contentType = MediaType.parse(MEDIA_TYPE);
    return RequestBody.create(contentType, new File(filePath));
}
```

The code above succeeded.

What is the equivalent of Retrofit ?

I tried and failed :
public interface UploadFileService {
   String CONTENT_TYPE = "image/jpeg";

```
/** base url, just for Retrofit usage demand. */
String BASE_URL = "https://not.used.net/";

/** Must be consistent with the following uploadFile annotation. */
String UPLOAD_FILE_HTTP_METHOD = "PUT";

@Multipart
@Headers("Content-Type:" + CONTENT_TYPE)
@PUT()
Observable<Response<MinaResponse<LocalAlbum.DummyResponse>>> uploadFile(@Url String url, @Part RequestBody fileBody);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Remove Multipart annotation and apply Body to fileBody,
I succeeded!

```
@Headers("Content-Type:" + CONTENT_TYPE)
@PUT()
Observable<Response<MinaResponse<LocalAlbum.DummyResponse>>> uploadFile(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody fileBody);
```