# how to upload any file image, video, pdf etc. using http put in android?

Tags: android, file-upload

I am working on an application that has the feature of uploading images, videos, pdf etc. Now the API is created using the **HTTP PUT** method. I have tried examples of retrofit using HTTP POST but I haven't found a working sample for HTTP PUT. If anyone has some knowledge about how to upload files of any size to the server, then please help me out. I am stuck on this from last week. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004791/how-to-use-retrofit-to-upload-a-file-with-http-put

Comment: @Om thanks for your reply, bro i am able to upload images below 5mb to server but i have few issues above 5mb. I want a working code for bigger files too.